# Memory leak while using std::move

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I got class which contains unique_ptr array with following constructor

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : p_capacity(2), p_size(0) {
    p_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity);     
}
```

I want to reinitialize it later in member method like this, moving old array into new array thats 2 times bigger

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::extendArray() {
    p_capacity *= 2;
    const auto &srcArray = p_array.get();
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> destArray = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity);;
    std::move(srcArray, std::next(srcArray, p_capacity/2), destArray.get());    
}
```

It seems to work, it compiles, extends my array like I want, but valgrind check shown this:

```
==17698== Invalid write of size 4
==17698==    at 0x4030D4: MyVector<int>::pushBack(int const&) (my_vector.cpp:17)
==17698==    by 0x402D9F: main (main.cpp:13)
==17698==  Address 0x542bc88 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==17698==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17698==    by 0x404907: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
==17698==    by 0x403B68: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
==17698==    by 0x40329D: std::_MakeUniq<int []>::__array std::make_unique<int []>(unsigned long) (in /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
==17698==    by 0x403010: MyVector<int>::MyVector() (my_vector.cpp:5)
==17698==    by 0x402C9B: main (main.cpp:8)
==17698==
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the contents of the first array into new array

Comment: Yes, thats to point. Copy old array into new one which has bigger size. I know there is STL Vector I could use, but Im actually trying to do that on my own.

Comment: Then you don't use move for it .
Use std:copy or memcpy. Then reset you unique pointer. And assign a new unique ptr to the variable. 

Move is used to transfer  ownership. Not contents

Comment: Cant really get this done, could u help me with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

std::move does not move anything. It casts the argument to make it movable. See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

As @Ankur says in the comments, you need to use a function like std::memcpy (if T is trivial or POD) or std::copy.